# High order Count(P) in Dafny

Tags: arrays, count, predicate, higher-order-functions, dafny

I would like to use a high order `Count(P)` function over arrays like:

`Count(even, a)`, or `Count(higher_than_10, a)`, where the first parameter is the predicate and the second one the array.

That is, to count how many times this P proposition happens on an array.

Is there a way in Dafny to do this? I think that this kind of functions existed, but maybe their syntax has been changed or something.

Thanks

I already have looked at:

```
-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167124/dafny-and-counting-of-occurrences
-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379857/polymorphism-in-dafny
-https://gitter.im/dafny-lang/community?at=5d90c402086a72719e848f24
-https://www.imperial.ac.uk/events/104961/higher-order-functions-in-the-verification-aware-programming-language-dafny-k-rustan-m-leino/
```

Comment: It's not built-in, so you will have to define it yourself. Are you asking how to define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to define such a function.

```
function method CountHelper<T>(P: T -> bool, a: array<T>, i: int): int
  requires 0 <= i <= a.Length
  reads a
  decreases a.Length - i
{
  if i == a.Length
  then 0
  else (if P(a[i]) then 1 else 0) + CountHelper(P, a, i+1)
}

function method Count<T>(P: T -> bool, a: array<T>): int
  reads a
{
  CountHelper(P, a, 0)
}

method Main()
{
  var a := new int[10] (i => i);
  var evens := Count(x => x % 2 == 0, a);
  print evens, "\n";
  var bigs := Count(x => x >= 5, a);
  print bigs, "\n";
}
```

When run, it prints `5` twice, as expected.

```
$ dafny /compile:3 count.dfy
Dafny 3.0.0.20820

Dafny program verifier finished with 3 verified, 0 errors
Running...

5
5
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, I really really appreciate it! One question, why are not all these useful and in-other-languages-primitive functions integrated in Dafny?

Comment: I wouldn't call these operations "primitive" in other languages. Usually, they are in those languages' standard libraries. To a first approximation, Dafny doesn't have a standard library, which is kind of unfortunate. Not sure I have a great answer to "why?".

Comment: I agree, I meant the standard library. I am curious, because many functions are well-known and always studied in Dafny courses (such as factorial, fibonacci...), but not integrated.